# MS Access Query: Creating a Master table from premade query that selects records with most recent date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make a master table in ms access that constantly updates the records of the unique model numbers based upon the most recent date.

The premade table was created by using a select query that brings all the records of multiple tables and inserts them into a single table. Within each table there are multiple fields however the only relevant fields are the Model number field and the Date. Across the tables the unique model numbers are repeated, but their individual time stamps are different.

I need the master table to select the records with the most recent date and place the whole record into the master table.  I'm new to ms access and I don't know how I could do this. Any tips of suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: To get useful feedback you need to provide formatted table layouts with field names and data types you want in your select - and some basic example data showing what you have and what you want out of the query.

Comment: @dbmitch Yes, that is what I ended up figuring out, along with some SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you would need such a table then I'd say there's definitely something wrong with your database design.
Having said that, why don't you query on the most recent date of tables that hold Model Numbers?
It might help if you could elaborate on why you'd want to do this, as in why you have multiple tables that hold Model Numbers.
Maybe your current database design is open for improvement.

Kind regards,

Rene

Comment: the reason I have multiple tables is because our company is a manufacturing company and as a product goes through production, management wants to be able to see where a specific product is at any given time. Each product is assigned a specific MRN (Model reference number), they want to be able to see where it is at any given time by accessing the ms database. Each station in manufacturing has a computer station where they input data such as the mrn, station, and the time stamp. So as the product moves down the manufacturing line it can be estimated how long it will take for completion.

Comment: So why don't you track down the latest phase of the product?

Comment: I would like to make a table or query that tracks the most updated entry of that particular product, however I don't know how to do that or even where to begin. I am a complete novice when it comes to vba, sql, access and excel. I just started to learn how to use them last month. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. If a product moves down the line you should be able to look into some sort of manufacturing IT system to locate the product at any given time. Are you saying you don't have such an IT system that enables you to track and trace any product at any time?

Comment: Exactly, I was tasked to make an interface to do this and then log it into a database, I have made the interface, I was having trouble to make a solid database for management. However yesterday I solved my own problem.